# End user get multiple copies of same email content

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on ASP.NET web application (C# Language). One of my task is to send email to 1000 to 2000 person at a time.

I got problems like some end users(Email Receivers) got duplication multiple copies of same email content.

This method will call one by one as per new email address got from list. Due to privacy I remove some part of this method.

```
  [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
        public static CampMaster SendMailContinue(int CustId)
        {
            try
            {

Customers Customer = null;
                    Customer = Customers.GetbyCustNextId(CustId,true).FirstOrDefault();

                string sTemplate = "Here will be Template content.";

                #region SendMail

                    if (IsValidEmail(Customer.Email))
                    {
                        if (Globals.SendMail(sTemplate, FromEmailAddress, FromName, ToEmail,EmailSubject))
                        {
                            //Sent Success
                        }
                    }
                sTemplate = string.Empty;

                return true;
                #endregion
            }
        }
        catch (System.Threading.ThreadAbortException)
        {
                return null;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
                return null;
        }
```

//Client Side Code by Call WebMethod.

```
 function SendMailContinue(CustId, true) {
            PageMethods.SendMailContinue(CustId, true, OnGetSuccessSendMailContinue, OnGetFailureSendMailContinue);
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: You have not given us any code to help you with.. This sounds more like a debugging problem, have you checked there are no duplicate email addresses in your list?

Comment: Yes, I have checked out for that also, there is all Unique email addresses in the list not duplicate email addresses.

Comment: Would you please share your source code.

Comment: ok, just give me few mins.

Comment: And from where you are calling this method, I mean how you are populating your list of customers and sending them emails, share that part too.

Comment: There is not any Issue from code Its working fine!

Comment: Share your client side code. I think you are calling this method using ajax. You may want to share that code also.

Comment: please, have a look I update Javascript function by calling Webmethod.

Comment: So one email gets sent per ajax request? If so you probably have a list that you are iterating on the client which contains either the same customer more than once, or you have separate customer with the same email address.

Comment: I would also contend that having the client (browser) be responsible for calling the webmethod 1000-2000 times is not an ideal architectural design. What if the user just decides to browse some lolcats while he is "waiting for the email to get sent"..?